# Undefined error in switch when trying to reach a variable in same function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a variable that has done calculations in it, i.e.
'utTre' which consists of different variables to achieve the calculation I want.
When I try to see if it works, aka alert or just putting it to a span, it works.

But when I try to put it in my switch it just becomes undefined

I expect it to be put in a span I've put at the bottom of the page just to try it, but it becomes undefined. When I just do an alert or 
`document.getElementById("print1").innerHTML = utTre;`
outside the switch, it goes to the span with the id of print1

```js
function myFunction() {
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
  var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt3").value);
  var x = (52 * y) + (52 * z) + b;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

  var five = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt5").value);
  var six = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt6").value);
  var seven = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt7").value);
  var eight = document.getElementById("txt8").value;

  var utEtt = x * 0.10;
  var utTva = utEtt * eight;
  var utTre = utTva * five;


  /*document.getElementById("print1").innerHTML = utTre;
  alert(utTre);*/

  var valj = document.getElementById("selecting");
  var valjValue = valj.options[valj.selectedIndex].value;


  switch (valjValue) {

    case 'all':
      var result1 = "Gas/Petrol consumption is: ".utTre;
      document.getElementById("print1").innerHTML = result1;
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please click edit then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide HTML in a [mcve] - I made you the snippet. just "edit above snippet" and add HTML. You have a php-type concatenation in your code `"Gas/Petrol consumption is: ".utTre;` should be `"Gas/Petrol consumption is: "+ utTre;`

Comment: Also recommended to have recognisable variable names

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To concat value and string in JS you need to use `+` instead of `.`:

```
 var result1 = "Gas/Petrol consumption is: " + utTre;
```

Comment: Please do not answer typographical mistakes

Comment: typo-like. Enough to not warrant an answer but just a comment